# How to append tuples from for loop to list

Tags: python, list

```
inter = []

for inter in intersections:

    a, b = inter
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(6):
            lines_edges[int(b) + i, int(a) + j] = [0, 0, 255]
            cv2.circle(lines_edges,(int(a),int(b)), 5, (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)


print(inter)
```

OUTPUT:

```
(255.49047141424273, 253.22266800401204)
(261.42908992416034, 227.0)
(312.7111046847889, 227.0)
(361.3178929765886, 296.4939799331104)
(362.0041891809848, 227.5)
(362.5263157894737, 165.73684210526315)
(410.92892156862746, 228.5)
(463.1585111920874, 228.5)
```

OUTPUT I WANT:

```
[(255.49047141424273, 253.22266800401204) (261.42908992416034, 227.0) (312.7111046847889, 227.0) (361.3178929765886, 296.4939799331104) (362.0041891809848, 227.5) (362.5263157894737, 165.73684210526315) (410.92892156862746, 228.5) (463.1585111920874, 228.5)]
```

Comment: listObj.append(tupleObj)

Comment: You create an `inter` variable at the top of your code, but then you use it as the active variable in a loop. When you do that, `inter` gets repeatedly replaces with one item from `intersections`, and when the loop finishes, `inter` will just hold the last item from `intersections`. You probably need to use a different name either for the main list you are trying to create or for the active variable in the loop (both currently `inter`).

Comment: Did you try copying and pasting your question title [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+to+append+tuples+from+for+loop+to+list)? It appears that you already know the word `append` for what you want to do, so that is already a big head start. If you really don't know these kinds of things, you should learn them from a tutorial or documentation. On the other hand, if you thought you wrote it correctly but were confused by the result, then you should put in your own effort first to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to:

1. Prepare the empty array for result
2. Append the tuple to the array by using `append()`

For example:

```
result = []
tuples = [(1,2), (3,4)]
for tuple in tuples:
    result.append(tuple)
```

Or if you want to construct tuples from operations like you want the list have tuples containing the min and max for each input tuple, you can do:

```
result = []
tuples = [(3,1,7,2), (3,4,2,1)]
for tuple in tuples:
    inner_tuple = (min(tuple), max(tuple))
    result.append(inner_tuple)
```

I used the list of tuples above just as reference, the thing you only need is the use of `.append()` in the for loop.

You need to change the variable name to contain the result, because when you set the variable `inter` to be the inner element of the `intersections`, the `inter` will be no longer an empty array, so you need to change it:

```
# Change inter to result
result = [] 
for inter in intersections:
    # do things here...
    item = .....
    result.append(item)

print(result)
```

Comment: I dont want to append list of tuples, just want to append the whole output of that loop which have only tuples. in above i make inter = []  as emplty list

Comment: But you make the `inter` as inner elements of `intersection`, so it can do things inconsistently

Comment: The Output you wanted in the question has list of tuples type.

Comment: int obejct has no attribute append

Comment: @Prem You can't use the variable `inter` twice, so you need to change any

Answer (score 0):

You just have to append tuple in inter list in loop only.

```
inter.append(tuple)
```

Comment: int object has no attribute append

Comment: inter is list and not int so it will append tuple object in list.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = []
for inter in intersections:

    a, b = inter

    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(6):

            lines_edges[int(b) + i, int(a) + j] = [0, 0, 255]
            cv2.circle(lines_edges,(int(a),int(b)), 5, (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)


    s.append(inter)
a = [(int(x), int(y)) for x,y in s]
print(a)
```